# ListView item click event MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, eventtrigger

I have a MenuItem with ListView inside. What I want is when I click on a ListView item, some command fires. Here is my code:

```
<MenuItem Header="?">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CommentTemplateList}" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommentTemplate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PasteTemplate}"
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedCommentTemplate}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
</MenuItem>
```

Everything is ok, but command PasteTemplate fires only when selection is changed, and I need to it fire every time I click on the item. If I change EventName to one from the list (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx), for example MouseDown, the command does not fire at all.

Answer (score 4):

To accomplish this, while respecting the MVVM architecture, the best way is to add the specific behavior to your xaml code as follows;

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListView"
           ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleItems, Mode=OneWay}"
           SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
           IsItemClickEnabled="True">
     <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
             <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemClickCommand}" />
         </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
     </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
 </ListView>
```

And in your View Model, after declaring an IComand property as follows,

```
public ICommand ItemClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_itemClickCommand == null)
        {
            _itemClickCommand = new RelayCommand<ItemClickEventArgs>(OnItemClick);
        }

        return _itemClickCommand;
    }
}
```

Define the command as if you were handling the event in the code behind as follows;

```
private void OnItemClick(ItemClickEventArgs args)
{
    ListDataItem item = args?.ClickedItem as ListDataItem; 
    //DO what ever you want with the Item you selected in the click
}
```

Note: RelayCommand is used to handled commands using the MVVMLight Framework.

Comment: This functions 100% for me I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the **Preview**MouseDown event of the `ListViewItem` as suggested here:

[WPF MVVM Light Multiple ListBoxItems bound to same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022595/wpf-mvvm-light-multiple-listboxitems-bound-to-same-object)

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OnMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ..
</ListView>
```

If you don't want to invoke the command of the view model from the code-behind you could wrap the same functionality in an attached behaviour: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/28959/introduction-to-attached-behaviors-in-wpf.

There is more information an example on the link above.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna use 'SelectionChanged', You can reset the selection after your code. Just add that on your PasteTemplate

```
if(((ListView)sender).SelectedIndex == -1)return;
//your code
((ListView)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;
```

So, after your code, ListView has no selected elements. So if you click it again, the selection is changed again and code fires again.

Note: you can use MouseDown for it too, but it's a little tricky. For example, if user clicks none of your items but somewhere else inside your ListView like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWucX.png), it fires again with your current selection.

Comment: I am using MVVM, so i have binded Listview SelectedIndex property to SelectedTemplateIndex variable. 
My code: XAML: 

    `SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTemplateIndex}" `

ViewModel: 
`private void OnPasteTemplateExecute() { if (SelectedTemplateIndex == `      `-1) return; LeaveCommentBox = SelectedCommentTemplate.Description;` `SelectedTemplateIndex = -1; }`

And i see the same behaviour - command fires only if selection is actually changing.

Comment: `SelectedTemplateIndex=-1` should resets your selection. It selects -1st element (in listview, that means select nothing) and lets you select again.

if its still not resets, you can try reset your SelectedItem or check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18462019/7538242)